# Dynamic Reporting in R

Tags: r, dynamic, reporting, rtf

I am looking for a help to generate a 'rtf' report from R (dataframe).

I am trying output data with many columns into a 'rtf' file using following code

```
library(rtf)
inp.data <- cbind(ChickWeight,ChickWeight,ChickWeight)

outputFileName = "test.out"
rtf<-RTF(paste(".../",outputFileName,".rtf"), width=11,height=8.5,font.size=10,omi=c(.5,.5,.5,.5))
addTable(rtf,inp.data,row.names=F,NA.string="-",col.widths=rep(1,12),header.col.justify=rep("C",12))
done(rtf)
```

The problem I face is, some of the columns are getting hide (as you can see last 2 columns are getting hide). I am expecting these columns to print in next page (without reducing column width).

Can anyone suggest packages/techniques for this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: See [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/), output can be saved as Word, PDF, HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Six years later, there is finally a package that can do exactly what you wanted.  It is called [reporter](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reporter) (small "r", no "s").  It will wrap columns to the next page if they exceed the available content width.

```
library(reporter)
library(magrittr)

# Prepare sample data
inp.data <- cbind(ChickWeight,ChickWeight,ChickWeight)

# Make unique column names
nm <- c("weight", "Time", "Chick", "Diet")
nms <- paste0(nm, c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4)))
names(inp.data) <- nms

# Create table
tbl <- create_table(inp.data) %>% 
  column_defaults(width = 1, align = "center") 

# Create report and add table to report
rpt <- create_report("test.rtf", output_type = "RTF", missing = "-") %>% 
  set_margins(left = .5, right = .5) %>% 
  add_content(tbl)

# Write the report
write_report(rpt)
```

Only thing is you need unique columns names.  So I added a bit of code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If *docx* format can replace *rtf* format, use package `ReporteRs`.

```
library( ReporteRs )

inp.data <- cbind(ChickWeight,ChickWeight,ChickWeight)
doc = docx( )

# uncomment addSection blocks if you want to change page
# orientation to landscape
# doc = addSection(doc, landscape = TRUE ) 

doc = addFlexTable( doc, vanilla.table( inp.data ) )

# doc = addSection(doc, landscape = FALSE ) 

writeDoc( doc, file = "inp.data.docx" )
```